# laravel malforming URLs on prod environment

Tags: php, http, laravel-4

I have a controller function that gets called and returns a redirect_url to an AJAX request.

This is created using this call:

URL::to('model/configuration/'. $data->id )

In both production and local, there is a "prefix" url before the "model/" part of the URL. For example, the final url may look like part1/part2/model/configuration/8.

On production, the "part1/part2" part is not being generated by the URL::to() call.

Any idea why this is occurring and how to fix it?

full route definitions:

```
Route::post('model/configuration/{order_id}', ModelController@configUpdate');

Route::get('model/configuration/{order_id}', 'ModelController@model');
```

Comment: Can you provide the full route definition from `routes.php` for your `model/configuration/{id}` route?

Comment: done. added to original post

Comment: Just an idea. The URL::to($path) is using the root URL specified in your config files. Do you have that part1/part2 included in your local but not in your production version?

Answer (score 1):

You mention a 'prefix' in your question, but I didn't see any in your route definitions.  Regardless, I don't think `URL::to()` actually verifies that a route exists, and you can use it to make non-existent links to within your application (for whatever good that will do you).

I would suggest for you to instead [name your route](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes), and then you can leverage the `URL::route()` method instead:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function() {
    Route::get('test2', [ 'as' => 'testing', function() {
        var_dump(URL::route('testing'));
    }]);
});
```

This will output the following URL:

```
string 'http://server.com/test/test2' (length=28)
```

Comment: I meant prefix as in where the main website ends and the laravel app/routes begin.